# Firebase Flutter Streambuilder Filter

Tags: flutter

I am working on having image posts in a **Streambuilder** where I'd like the user to skip content on a **PageViewBuilder** if it's reported by her/him. What I have below works and says 'Reported user or content please scroll down or up' on the reported content however I'd like the user to skip theses pages if they are reported. How can I skip content with the below setup? Is there some sort of filter I can place in the Streambuilder? Maybe with listener on ScrollController or PageController?

```
  PageController pageController = PageController();


StreamBuilder(
  stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
     .collection("posts").snapshots(),
         builder: (context,
             AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> snapshot) {
                    return PageView.builder(
                      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
 controller:
                          pageController,
                      itemCount: snapshot.data?.docs.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        var ownerUid = snapshot.data?.docs[index]['ownerUid'];
                        var flagged = snapshot.data?.docs[index]['flagged'];
                        var imageUrl = snapshot.data?.docs[index]['imageUrl'];
                        return FutureBuilder(
                          future: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                              .collection('users')
                              .doc(ownerUid)
                              .get(),
                          builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot asyncsnapshot) {
                            if (asyncsnapshot.hasData) {
                              var owner = asyncsnapshot.data;
                              if (owner['flaggedby']
                                      .toString()
                                      .contains(currentuseruid ?? '') ||
                                  flagged.contains(user?.uid)) {
                                return const Center(
                                    child: Text(
                                        'Reported user or content please scroll down or up'));
                              }
                              return SingleChildScrollView(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

Flutter SDK installation appears corrupted: expected to find the directory
C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\flutter_app\dartsdk-windows-x64-release\flutter\packages\flutter_tools but it does not exist!
Please go to https://flutter.dev/setup for instructions on how to re-install Flutter.